# Application of the Hölder-inequality

Tags: inequality

Does this inequality

$$|x-y|^{2}\leq2|x|^{2}+2|y|^{2}$$

follows from the Hölder inequality?

Thank you!

Comment: Tell us what _you_ think.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ reals ?

Comment: you can just as well replace all the modulus brackets by regular brackets, the rest is just algebra (if x and y are real).

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that it follows from the Hoelder-inequality and yes, x and y are reals. I was just not sure, if I have to apply the triangle-inequality first and then Hoelder

Comment: Or if only Hoelder is ok, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left\|x-y\right\|^2 = \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2 - 2\langle x,y\rangle \color{red}{\leq} \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2\|x\| \|y\| \leq 2(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)$$
by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, that is a particular case of Holder's inequality.

Comment: If $x,y\in\Bbb C$ then we need the slight change $-2\Re\langle x,\bar y\rangle$

Comment: x and y are $\in\mathbb{R}$. Thank you!!

Comment: @panda ok. In any case the inequality holds for complex numbers too.